How to disable scrolling in WebView
I need to disable scrolling in WebView. I just want to scroll horizonally. But now, it's not working.
My Flutter version is up to date.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Wrap WebView in a GestureDetector and implement onVerticalDragUpdate():
GestureDetector(
    onHorizontalDragUpdate: (_) {},
    child: WebViewWidget(
        ...
    ),
)

